# Use of System.exit(0)

Tags: java, exit-code

```
public class WrapperTest {
    static {
        print(10);
    }

    static void print(int x) {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

In the above code `System.exit(0)` is used to stop the program. What argument does that method take? Why do we gave it as `0`. Can anyone explain the concept?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the [JAVA Documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit(int)):

> The argument serves as a status code;
>   by convention, a nonzero status code
>   indicates abnormal termination.

And [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exitcode) adds additional information.

Answer (score 7):

It's the return value that the Java process will report to the calling process.

It hasn't really got a precise definition, but the usual convention is that `0` means success and any non-zero value represents a failure.

Answer (score 3):

The argument is the return code which the java process will return (0 means "successful"). It can be used when a Java program is a part of a batch script, or by build tools such as Ant.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a **nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.**